# Referrer after updating app from Android Market

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play

In my application, I implemented a Broadcast Receiver that catches `com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER` intents launched by Android after an app is installed from the Market.

I am following the details here: http://code.google.com/mobile/analytics/docs/android/#referrals

Does this referrer catch updates too? In other words, can the user open the Google Play store with the referrer and update application?

Answer (score 7):

No, Google Play Store doesn't send `com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER` intent when the app is already installed.

If your app's package name is `com.example.android` your URL will be something like this.

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.android&referrer=testReferrer
```

When you open the URL while the app isn't installed you can see in the logcat this debug log from Play Store:

> 1857-1857/com.android.vending D/Finsky﹕ [1] 1.run: Capture referrer for com.example.android

When you open the same URL while the app is already installed you can see this log instead:

> 1857-1857/com.android.vending D/Finsky﹕ [1] 1.run: Dropped referrer for com.example.android because already-installed